# the SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was 5.5.1, Authentication required

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

I have been trying to get my application to send an email for over an hour now, and i've tried everything i've found online but i still get the exception mentioned in the title of my question.

Here is the code i used:

```
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Sender email", "Sender email password");
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("Sender email", "Sender");
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("My email"));
        mail.Subject = "TEST";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = sb.ToString();

        client.Send(mail);
```

I have allowed access to less secure apps on my account.
I have also tried enabling 2FA and then generating an application specific password, but the exception stays.

Comment: client.UseDefaultCredentials is set to false, as you can see in my code snippet, and in the actual code i did put the actual email and the password but for obvious reasons i removed those from the snippet.

Comment: Have you tried setting EnableSsl to false?

Comment: Did you turn on  "Acess for less secure apps" in your gmail settings ?

Comment: Or, actually, have you "Enabled SSL" in the web project?

Comment: I did turn on Access for less secured apps, i put that in the question, i have also tried setting enableSsl to false. i have found the solution now though and have edited the question

Comment: Yup That's what I have mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Check your gmail account and turn on "Acess for less secure apps"
2. Set `client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;` before `client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Sender email", "Sender email password");`